# Can I permanently set column visibility in the Content pane of Adobe Bridge CS5?

Tags: cs5, adobe-bridge

I remove all the columns I don't want visible by right-clicking the column headers and deselecting the column from the list. But when I switch to a different directory of images all the columns are back. They've even reverted in the directory I removed them from...

How do i make my changes stick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the appearance the way you want it, go to `Window > Workspaces > New Workspace` and save your custom workspace (call it "Pete's Custom" or whatever). It will show up as a new choice in the workspace list at the top of the Bridge window.

When you close Bridge, your new custom layout will remain the default.

Comment: I tried doing this 3 times, and each time I saved the workspace, it showed the new workspace as selected but the columns reverted to the state of all being present. I'm going to try and force the program to recreate it's preference file and see if that make a difference.

Comment: Yes, that would be the right next debug step. A workspace is normally sticky.

Comment: In a followup, I've recently dropped Bridge altogether and am using the screaming fast ACDSee Pro 7. It costs, but it's really fast and pretty powerful.